# Mixing and choosing CWDM and DWDM parts

Tags: fiber

I have been looking at the page ["Cisco Enhanced Wavelength Division Multiplexing Product Line"](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/modules/ps5455/product_data_sheet0900aecd806a1c36.html), on Cisco's web site. I would like to light up some dark fibre for at least 2x 10Gbps Ethernet links. Looking at that page, can I use the eDWM box (EWDM-OADM4) on it's own to get 4x10Gbps links over a dark fibre pair, or do I need to have both boxes at both ends (EWDM-OADM4 & CWDM-MUX8A)?

Also, not having done this before; I have looked around and found tuned DWDM X2 optics such as [10GDWDM-X2-38.98=](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/modules/ps5455/ps6576/data_sheet_c78_489725.html), (SFP+ devices also exist that are tuned to DWDM frequencies like this). Should these "just work" when connected directly into the eWDM mux above and a switch of my choosing (that supports the chosen transeciever type be it SPF+ or X2)? I assume the IOS will be ignorant of the SFP+/X2 being tuned, that is the point of them, and they will function like normal?

Comment: You really need to ask Cisco on this.

Comment: Dont know these products, but surely you need one per side. Cisco switches are aware of colored sfps.

Comment: @3molo : They are aware ay? So does this mean they don't work on all switches then?

Comment: Yes, aware of a WDM SFP but not necessarily the wavelength of it. If it's cisco compatible it'll work on all nexus/catalyst switches I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.)  Yes - you need an EWDM device on each side of the link.  This is what separates out the frequency of light a given port is concerned with.

2.) The EWDM documentation has a list of compatible optics and part numbers.  In -general- all you need to do is pop the optic into the router/switch, hook up a single mode patch and you're good to go, but the documentation for your equipment will explicitly list which optics are compatible.  As a general rule issues are usually in much newer equipment - so a Catalyst 6500 pretty much supports everything while a Nexus 5000 might need a newer version of code for a particular optic.

Comment: Yes I can confirm this is correct after speak with other individuals also. Everything should work just fine. I don't need the CWDM-MUX8A as per the exampe on the page, the EWDM-OADM4 would work fine on its own. Also using coloured optics directly into the mux is fine. Cheers!